# How to ask for multiple inputs and stop when user enters 0?

Tags: java, loops, input

My Program is supposed to receive numerous numbers of money, and convert it to change, but when it receives a `0`, it should stop asking for a input and stop the program.

I have all the math right, I am just having problems with the repeat asking for the numbers. Here is what I have currently:

```
public class Coins {

    public static int quarters;
public static int dimes;
public static int nickels;
public static int pennies;

    public static int Quarters(int TotalCoins) {
        quarters = (int) (TotalCoins / 25);
        TotalCoins %= 25;
        return quarters;
    }
    public static int Dimes(int TotalCoins){
        TotalCoins -= (quarters * 25);
        dimes = (int) (TotalCoins / 10);
        TotalCoins %= 10;
        return dimes;
}
    public static int Nickels(int TotalCoins){
        TotalCoins -= (dimes * 10) + (quarters * 25);
        nickels = (int) (TotalCoins / 5);
        TotalCoins %= 5;
        return nickels;
    }
    public static int Pennies(int TotalCoins){
        TotalCoins -= (nickels * 5 ) + (dimes * 10 ) + (quarters * 25);
        pennies = (int) (TotalCoins / 1);
        TotalCoins %= 1;
        return pennies;
    }
}
```

And this is my tester class (where I'm pretty sure my main problem is):

```
public class CoinsTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {           
        Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);

        if (kybd.nextInt() != 0){
            int changeMoney = kybd.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Quarters = " + Coins.Quarters(changeMoney) + "\nDimes = " + Coins.Dimes(changeMoney) + "\nNickels = " + Coins.Nickels(changeMoney) + "\nPennies = " + Coins.Pennies(changeMoney));              
        }
    }
}
```

Any Help would be Great.

EDIT: Someone told me it might be easier to do the whole thing in one class, if so, any suggestions doing it that way would be excellent as well. ThankYou!!!
EDIT: I forgot to mention that i should be able to input all the numbers then the output being displayed of all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true) { 
    int changeMoney = kybd.nextInt();
    if (changeMoney == 0)
        break;

    // do stuff with changeMoney
}
```

it can also be expressed as a `for` loop:

```
Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int changeMoney = kybd.nextInt(); changeMoney != 0; changeMoney = kybd.nextInt()) {
    // do stuff with changeMoney 
}
```

and while less lines, it makes the for loop line quite long, but that can be alleviated by using shorter variable names:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = in.nextInt(); i != 0; i = in.nextInt()) {
    // do stuff with i
}
```

Comment: Great code. My fault to forget to mention (sorry about this) that i should be able to enter all the input numbers at once, how would i do this would you say?

Comment: Create a loop inside the while loop that collects several inputs, then use all the inputs. If *one* of the inputs is zero, you could break

Comment: @SplattColor i edit my answer for a possible solution storing inputs in a `List`

Answer (score 2):

You are asking user for number twice

- once in condition,
- second inside your `if` statement.

Also it seems that your `if` should be replaced with loop if you want let user to write another number again. In this case you can use something like

```
Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int changeMoney = -1; (changeMoney = kybd.nextInt()) != 0;){
    System.out.println("Quarters = " + Coins.Quarters(changeMoney) + "\nDimes = " + Coins.Dimes(changeMoney) + "\nNickels = " + Coins.Nickels(changeMoney) + "\nPennies = " + Coins.Pennies(changeMoney));
}
```

Advantage of this approach is that it is short and `changeMoney` will be local variable available only inside loop.

Comment: +1 nice in-line kung fu to DRY the `nextInt()`, but some think it poor style to assign-and-test like that.

Comment: @Bohemian Damn. Now I realised it is the same approach as from your answer. +1 for you and will get back to my previous version.

Answer (score 1):

First, your methods should have lower case names. Second, you need a loop - perhaps like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);

  while (kybd.hasNextInt()){ // will stop if the next input is not an int.
    int changeMoney = kybd.nextInt();
    if (changeMoney == 0) {
      break;
    }
    // Assuming you just rename them to "get" methods.
    System.out.println("Quarters = "
        + Coins.getQuarters(changeMoney) + "\nDimes = "
        + Coins.getDimes(changeMoney) + "\nNickels = "
        + Coins.getNickels(changeMoney)
        + "\nPennies = "
        + Coins.getPennies(changeMoney));
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 nice suggestion, i like the 3 different ways in answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Change it to something like this.

```
 int changeMoney=0;
 while ( (changeMoney =kybd.nextInt()) != 0){           
     System.out.println("Quarters = " + Coins.Quarters(changeMoney) + "\nDimes = " + Coins.Dimes(changeMoney) + "\nNickels = " + Coins.Nickels(changeMoney) + "\nPennies = " + Coins.Pennies(changeMoney));    
 }
```

> in @Bohemian answer :Great code. My fault to forget to mention (sorry about this) that i
>   should be able to enter all the input numbers at once, how would i do
>   this would you say?

Store the inputs in a collection like a `List`.

Code example:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();          
while ( (int i =kybd.nextInt()) != 0){           
     list.add(i);
}
// Then loop again
for(Integer changeMoney : list){
     System.out.println("Quarters = " + Coins.Quarters(changeMoney) + "\nDimes = " + Coins.Dimes(changeMoney) + "\nNickels = " + Coins.Nickels(changeMoney) + "\nPennies = " +      Coins.Pennies(changeMoney)); 
}
```

Comment: @SplattColor +1 is when actually you upvote an answer xD.. Consider accepting one of the answers provided to get finish this question  and upvote who actually you consider answer helpful to solve your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're reading only once, you should probably wrap the scanner.nextInt() call in a while loop that break if the value is 0

```
while (kybd.hasNextInt()){
   int changeMoney = kybd.nextInt();
   if(changeMoney == 0)break;

   System.out.println("Quarters = " + Coins.Quarters(changeMoney) + "\nDimes = " + Coins.Dimes(changeMoney) + "\nNickels = " + Coins.Nickels(changeMoney) + "\nPennies = " + Coins.Pennies(changeMoney));

}
```